# How to count the number of zeros if they lie between ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe

```
ID   A  B  C
60   0  1  1
120  0  1  1
180  0  1  1
240  0  0  0
300  0  0  0 
360  1  1  0
420  1  1  1
480  0  0  0
540  0  0  0 
600  0  0  0
660  0  0  0
720  1  1  1
780  1  0  1
840  0  0  0
900  0  0  0
```

How to count the number of zeros only between 1

in this example, the answer should be [4] in A, [2,4] in B, [3,4] in C

Could you help me, please?

i have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67047289/count-number-of-zeros-after-every-non-zero-clusters-in-python) option, but it does not fit, since it counts all zeros in a row. And I need to count zeros only between 1. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like `bfill` and `ffill` then `groupby` the result

```
s = (df.mask(df==0).ffill() == df.mask(df==0).bfill()) & (df==0)
s = s.apply(lambda x : x[x].groupby((~x).cumsum()).count().tolist())
ID        []
A        [4]
B     [2, 4]
C     [3, 4]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, I do not know how, but it works. I'm going to study these methods. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

df.apply(lambda s: [g for k,g in [(k, len(list(g))) 
                                  for k,g in groupby(s, lambda x: x==0)
                                 ][1:-1] if k])
```

Output:

```
ID        []
A        [4]
B     [2, 4]
C     [3, 4]
dtype: object
```